# Как передавать данные между двумя компьютерами в python?

Tags: python

Я хочу создать игру на двоих в python. Мне нужен простой и удобный способ передавать данные между двумя компьютерами. Есть идеи?

Comment: Сокеты, других способов просто нет

Comment: @andreymal На низком уровне да. На высоком куча всего, например websockets.

Comment: вот такая штука может быть подойдет https://github.com/chr15m/PodSixNet

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan О прикольно! А под 3.x работает?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor мопед не мой, но автор пишет что да )

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan ок, как-нибудь попробую. ;)

Comment: В python 2 выдает ошибку: line 7, in <module>
    sock.connect(('localhost', 100))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 10061] Подключение не установлено,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Рекомендую вам воспользоваться socket'ами. Вот простой пример. Сервер реагирует на команду say hello и пишет hello в консоль, когда клиент эту команду посылает.
Server:

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            if data == b'say hello':
                print("hello")
```

Client:

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 65432        # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b'say hello')
```

[Начать учить](https://habr.com/ru/post/149077/), [продолжить](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/). Удачи!